# Permission for drive

Tags: macbook-pro, permission, windows

I've installed Windows beside macOS. My MacBook now has two drives.

- Drive "A" and Drive "B".
- Drive "A" has macOS boot and Drive "B" Windows 7.

The problem now is that I can't modify drive A when I'm working with Windows 7. I have to log out from there, boot to macOS and then do the changes like cut, delete etc folders or files.

Is there any solution that would solve this problem (preferably without formatting the drive)?

Comment: Hi. The permissions are set up very intentionally to let the system run safely.  You never need to format just to change permissions, so we might need you to State clearly what solution you think would work or maybe edit the question to rephrase what the end goal is. Punctuation and spelling errors make it hard to even guess if you’re in windows or macOS when you are having this problem.

Comment: Did you create any "shared" folders or drive partitions?

Comment: I've tidied a bit, but I'm assuming the issue is that Win can't read HFS/APFS & Mac, whilst being able to read, won't be able to write to NTFS. This does need clarification, though, as already mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

When Macs were first able to run Windows 7 (SP1), the Boot Camp Support Software installed the software necessary to allow reading of Mac OS Extended (Journaled) volumes from Windows. Also, OS X (macOS) could read from Windows NTFS volumes.  Neither Apple nor Microsoft provided a way to allow writing to the other operating system's volumes.

> Unfortunately, as Apple has progresses toward the new APFS format, some (if not all) Windows Boot Camp installations have loss the ability to read from macOS volumes.

A possible solution would be to purchase a third party product such as the [Mac ToolBox](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/mac-toolbox/) from Paragon Software.

Another possible solution would be to create another separate FAT32 or ExFAT formatted drive. You could  then use the drive for storage of files used by both operating systems or to transfer files between operating systems.

Finally, if you have a high speed internet connection, then you could copy small files to your iCloud drive and access the files from both macOS and Windows.